# WHERE clause with empty string doesn't return any rows

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have an iOS app which I built an API to extract some data from a SQL Server database. When my app sends a query with an empty string, it doesn't return any rows, even though it should.

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>db, "UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pass);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($ip, $connectionInfo);
    if ( $conn ) {
        //connected
    }
    else {
        echo "Error:"; echo "<br>";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    /**************************************/
    /*              RETRIEVAL             */
    /**************************************/
    $prod = new StdClass(); $arr = array(); $temp = array();

    $search = $_GET['search'];
    $search = "%$search%";
    $sql = "SELECT
                name, qty
            FROM
                table
            WHERE
                name LIKE ?";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, array($search));
    sqlsrv_execute( $stmt );
    $i = 0;
    if ( $stmt === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }
    else {
        while ( $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $newProd = clone $prod;
            $newProd->mainInfo =  $row['name'];
            $newProd->secondInfo = $row['qty'];
            $arr[] = $newProd;
        }
    }
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode($arr);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

I built the API with PHP and Apache on macOS where it worked as intended. When I copied the files on a Windows server, if my app accessed a link similar to `192.168.0.102/file.php?search=` it would return no rows on Windows, and in macOS it would return all the rows of the table, as I wanted to. I know the script works and there are no issues, because if my app accesses a link similar to `192.168.0.102/file.php?search=someName` it returns the corresponding rows. I want the app to display all the rows if the variable `search` is empty. Should I use some other way to achieve this, or is it some mistake on my part.

Comment: I’ve tried the CONCAT and reflex method from the link you provided and I still can’t display anything. Normally, my method should work, but something funky is happening.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by not using sql condition when "search" $_GET param is not supplied or is empty.

Example how to achieve that, change your code from:

```php
$search = $_GET['search'];
$search = "%$search%";
$sql = "SELECT
                name, qty
            FROM
                table
            WHERE
                name LIKE ?";
```

to something like this:

```php
$search = null;

if (true === array_key_exists('search', $_GET) && false === empty($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%';
}

$sql = "SELECT name, qty FROM table";

if (false === is_null($search)) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE name LIKE ?';
}
```

Comment: It still returns empty, unfortunately. I can't find the issue and it's driving me crazy. Another thing i noticed, if i search like `someIP/file.php?search=a` it still won't return anything. Only on the second letter, it return rows. Maybe it has something to do with the SQL Sever?

Comment: No errors are printed (check if error displaying is disabled) ?

Comment: Not at all. The script works fine if I search with more than two letters.

Comment: Have you tried executing query directly on sql server ? (as you guessed it may be something wil sql server). Or try to get "last executed query" to see if correct query is generated.

Comment: Not quite. I thought that running the query in a terminal would yield the same result ( I don’t have access to the actual database, since it is used by another app and I only have the credentials and the table structures).

Comment: I found query to return last executed queries, so try it to check the generated query is correct. https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/find-last-few-executed-queries#highlighter_332171
`SELECT txt.TEXT AS [SQL Statement], qs.EXECUTION_COUNT [No.Times Executed], qs.LAST_EXECUTION_TIME AS [Last Time Executed],   DB_NAME(txt.dbid) AS [Database] FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_QUERY_STATS AS qs CROSS APPLY SYS.DM_EXEC_SQL_TEXT(qs.SQL_HANDLE) AS txt WHERE txt.dbid = DB_ID('{yourDatabaseName}') ORDER BY qs.LAST_EXECUTION_TIME DESC`

Comment: Starting to think there is something wrong with my PHP installation. Inserted the query, and there are no errors, a white, beautiful page. The thing is that if I misplace a semi colon or type wrong a column name, I get those errors. I’ll try running the script on Ubuntu and see if is windows/php specific issue.

Comment: hey @Saamoot , i managed to install the odbc and sqldrivers under ubuntu and ran the script. Guess what, it works perfectly. Now, the question is, why do i get a different result in Windows than linux and macos?

Comment: 1) You said you have access to terminal/console ? Have you tried running query for getting last executed queries in it ? If not try it after doing request `someIP/file.php?search=a` which cause problems and then check queries. 2) If "clean" installation is working on linux try re-installing drivers (odbc and sqlsrv) on windows machine to try "fresh" configuration or maybe update ?

Comment: I’ve tried the script on my Windows installation. I’ll install XAMP with the latest sqlsrv and odbc drivers on the server and see the result. This is what I can do in terms only “cleanest” installl.

Comment: Have you had time to try xamp ? Any luck ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven’t. Reinstalled XAMPP and got the newest drivers and still the same result. This wouldn’t be a problem since I am a Linux user, but my deployment target is a Windows Server and this is worrisome. Thank you for your time, you’ve been great help!